# How to parameterize the intersection of these two curves?

Tags: calculus, parametrization

So I am wondering about how to parameterize the curve of intersection of the two surfaces

$x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ (cylinder) and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (cone).

Should I solve both equation for one variable and set them equal to each other?

$x^2=1-(y-1)^2=z^2-y^2$

$1-(y^2-2y+1)^2=z^2-y^2$

$2y=z^2$ If I then set $z=t$ we must have that $y=\frac{1}{2}t^2$. From the equation to the cone we then have that

$x=\sqrt{z^2-y^2}=\sqrt{t^2-\frac{1}{4}t^4}$

Is this right?

Comment: Seems about right. Be careful though, you have to check which values of $t$ would make sense.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about finding my interval for the t. How do if find this interval?

Comment: Hint: Try to identify the conditions from your working that you assumed to be true while deriving your result. Then all the values of $t$ which result $(x,y,z)$ points such that those conditions are satisfied are appropriate.

Comment: Note that your parametrization for $x(t)$ does not allow negative values for $x$

Answer (score 1):

I parameterized as follows:

For the cone $(x,y,z) = ( r \cos t, r \sin t , r ) $

Plug this into the cylinder equation:

$r^2 \cos^2 t + (r \sin t - 1)^2  = 1$

So that,

$r^2 - 2 r \sin t = 0$

Hence,

$r = 2 \sin t$

Varying $t$ over $[0, 2\pi]$ gives $r$, which together with $t$ give $x, y, z$

$x =  2 \sin t \cos t  = \sin 2 t $

$y = 2 \sin^2 t = 1 - \cos 2 t $

$z = 2 \sin t  $

Since $z \ge 0 $, we must have $t \in [0, \pi] $

Comment: In your second equation $x^2 = r^2 \cos^2t \ne r^2$.

Comment: The resulting equation then is $r^2 = 2r\sin t$. $r$ is non-negative which means $\sin t \ge 0$. Then we can substitute back and get the parametrization of $x, y, z$.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry, I misread the equation of the cylinder.

Comment: This part is still not irght: "Varying $t$ over $[0,2\pi]$ gives r".  In cylindrical coordinates the parameter $r$ must be non-negative as I mentioned it above. Otherwise you should get the same result if you checked that $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \ge 0$, which implies that $2 \sin t \ge 0 \iff 0 + k 2\pi \le t \le \pi + k 2\pi$ for $\forall k\in\mathbb Z$ (of courese to make  your parametrization uniqu, you should only consider $t\in[0, \pi]$)

Comment: You're right.  I should restrict the interval to $[0, \pi]$